# Wifi wont connect Realtek rtl8188ee Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, realtek

So I have had ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS for a while with no problems. Then a few days ago I started the computer and my home wifi showed up in the menu but it was unable to connect. It tries for a while then shows up with "Activation of network connection failed". Also ethernet works fine. Oh and every other device in the house can connect to the wifi except for my laptop.

My computer is Toshiba Satellite C55-A5285. The wifi driver is rtl8188ee from Realtek.

The things I did so far was do a software update, boot in insecure mode, and tried to install 2 other drivers but then uninstalled them because they didn't work either. Of course I rebooted, shut down and all that at least 50 times lol. Also I looked at a lot of forums and videos already but they either didn't help, too outdated, or they were too complicated for my understanding.

I am an amateur, but yes I can use the terminal.

I hope you can help and if you need any more information about computer hardware software etc I will be happy to give it. Thank you!!!